# Rest Framework - filter foreign key results

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models within Django and I am trying to perform a filter such that only one foreign key value from a set is returned as part of the result set.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)

class Version(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField()
```

My serializer looks like this.

```
class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = (...)

class DocumentVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = VersionSerializer(source='version_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (...)
```

My RetrieveAPIView looks something like this:

```
class Search(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Document.objects.all().distinct()
    serializer_class = DocumentVersionSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super(Search, self).filter_queryset(queryset)
        queryset.filter(version__num=self.kwargs.get('version_num))
        return queryset
```

What I am after is the following, a Document object with 1 version which is set as part of the URL. So the URL could be something like: `/api/document/version/1.1/`

The json would be something like:

```
{
    "name": "test document",
    "version": {
        "num": "1.1",
    },
}
```

But I get:

```
{
    "name": "test document",
    "version": [
        {
            "num": "1.1",
        },
        {
            "num": "1.2",
        },
    ]
}
```

The problem I am having is that multiple version numbers are coming back in the json response. How can I limit the number of returned responses.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it using serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class VersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Version
        fields = (...)

class DocumentVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_version(self, Document):
            #select the one version that you want through queryset
            #and then serialize it with your VersionSerializer.

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (...)
```

Don't forget to list 'version' in your fields.
You can find the documentation for this method here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield